# Conflicting situations arising while solving for $x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers, roots

Given $$x^{1/4}+\frac{1}{x^{1/4}}=1$$

find $$x^{1024}+\frac{1}{x^{1024}}=?$$

My approach let $a=x^{1/4}$
$$a+\frac{1}{a}=1$$
$$a^2+1-a=0 $$
multiplying by $(a+1)$
$$(a+1)(a^2+1-a)=0 $$
$$a^3+1=0, a^3=-1$$
by solving we get value of $x$ 
$$x^3=1$$
Now the answer to the should be 2. 
$$x^{1024}+\frac{1}{x^{1024}}=2$$

But if we square the equation $$x^{1/4}+\frac{1}{x^{1/4}}=1$$
we will get $-1$ as the recurring digit on the RHS as we square on both the sides. Thus it will result in $-1$ as the answer.
Can anyone help me to figure out where I am wrong

Comment: I believe this can be solved using De Moivre's theorem

Comment: Here is your mistake :$x^3=1$.

Comment: Obviously, $-1$ is a solution to $(a+1)(a^2+1-a)=0$ but that doesn't mean it's a solution to $a^2+1-a=0,$ and it obviously isn't.  You introduced an extraneous solution when you multiplied by $a+1.$

Comment: @saulspatz Yes I understand now .

Comment: @peterlev But $a$ is not $-1$. it is $\frac{1\pm i\sqrt{3}}{2}$

Comment: Yes got it @hamam_Abdallah

Answer (score 2):

$\sqrt[4]x$ and $\frac{1}{\sqrt[4]x}$ are roots of the equation
$$z^2-z+1=0,$$ they are $\cos60^{\circ}+i\sin60^{\circ}$ and $\cos60^{\circ}-i\sin60^{\circ}$.

Id est,
$$x^{1024}+\frac{1}{x^{1024}}= (\cos60^{\circ}+i\sin60^{\circ})^{4096}+(\cos60^{\circ}-i\sin60^{\circ})^{4096}=$$
$$=(\cos60^{\circ}+i\sin60^{\circ})^{4+682\cdot6}+(\cos60^{\circ}-i\sin60^{\circ})^{4+682\cdot6}=$$
$$=\cos240^{\circ}+i\sin240^{\circ}+\cos240^{\circ}-i\sin240^{\circ}=-1.$$

Answer (score 1):

Since $a^3=-1$, one has $a^6=1$ and
$$ x=(x^\frac14)^4=a^4=-a. $$
So
$$ x^{1024}+\frac{1}{x^{1024}}=a^{1024}+\frac{1}{a^{1024}}=a^{6\cdot17+4}+\frac{1}{a^{6\cdot17+4}}=a^4+\frac{1}{a^4}=-a-\frac{1}{a}=-1$$